# Loading tables of different dimensions in infinite scroll page while minimizing empty space between tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, infinite-scroll

I have a website where users contribute with content. The content takes form of tables, where every td element is of equal height and width. The different pieces of content have different number of rows and columns. I want to stack these elements in an infinite-scroll webpage. ATM I'm doing this: I construct a table, in it a tr. I load element by element inside tds and count their number of columns. When a certain threshold has been reached, i break the tr and start a new tr. This makes the content elements border eachother sideways, leaving no room between each. However I also want to load the elements in such a way that there is minimal room between elements vertically. How can I do this?

Here is my code. I DO NOT expect to have it rewritten or have new code written for me. This is only to make it clearer to you what I am currently doing.

```
    <?php

    $row = 0;
    $column = 0;
    $maxColumns = 124;

    echo "<table><tr>";



    $listHandle = fopen('pieces/piecesList', 'r');
    while (!feof($listHandle)) {          

        echo "<td>";

        $filename = trim(fgets($listHandle));        
        $templateHandle = fopen("pieces/" . $filename, 'r');
        $thisLine = fgets($templateHandle);     
        list($lowestX, $highestX, $lowestY, $highestY) = sscanf($thisLine, '%d %d %d %d');
            //echo $lowestX .  $highestX . $lowestY . $highestY;
        $templateTable = "<table id=\"" . $filename . "\" title =\"" . $filename . "\">" . PHP_EOL;
        $greenCells = array();

        $fileLength = 0;

        while (!feof($templateHandle)) {                
            $thisLine = fgets($templateHandle);         
            list($thisX, $thisY) = sscanf($thisLine, '%d %d');
            $carrier = $thisX . " " . $thisY;
            array_push($greenCells, $carrier);
            $fileLength++;
        }

        for ($y = $lowestY; $y <= $highestY; $y++) {
             //   echo "inside for loop Y \n";
            $templateTable = $templateTable . "<tr>" . PHP_EOL;
            for ($x = $lowestX; $x <= $highestX; $x++) {

              //  echo $y . $x;
                $templateTable = $templateTable . "<td";
                $coordinateExists = FALSE;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $fileLength; $i++) {
                    if ($greenCells[$i] == $x . " " . $y) {
                        $coordinateExists = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                if ($coordinateExists) {
                    $templateTable = $templateTable . " class=\"green";
                    if ($x == 0 && $y == 0) {
                        $templateTable = $templateTable . " markerdot";
                    }
                    $templateTable = $templateTable . "\"";
                } else if ($x == 0 && $y == 0) {
                    $templateTable = $templateTable . " class=\"markerdot\"";
                }

                $templateTable = $templateTable . " x='" . $x . "' y='" . $y . "'>";
                $templateTable = $templateTable . "</td>" . PHP_EOL;
            }
            $templateTable = $templateTable . "</tr>" . PHP_EOL;
        }

        $templateTable = $templateTable . "</table> </td>";

        if ($column == 0) {
            $tallestTemplateHeight = $highestY - $lowestY;
        } else if (($highestY - $lowestY) > $tallestTemplateHeight) {
            $tallestTemplateHeight = $highestY - $lowestY;
        }

        echo $templateTable;

        $column += $highestX - $lowestX;
        if ($column >= $maxColumns) {
            $row += $tallestTemplateHeight;
            echo "</tr></table><table><tr>";
        }
    }
    fclose($listHandle);



    ?>  

</div>
```

PS: I am open to discarding my current setup entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw this out as an idea - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fgC7C/)

It uses divs instead of a table, and by playing with the loops, width, etc, you can adjust it as you see fit.

Everything fits together edge to edge.

JS

```
var counter = 0;
var numdivs = 8;
$('#clickme').click(function(){
  for(var i=1; i < 50; ++i)
  {
    $("<div class='standarddiv'>X</div>").appendTo('.holder');
    counter = counter + 1;
   if(counter==numdivs)
   {
    $("<div class='clearboth'></div>").appendTo('.holder');
    counter = 0;
    }
   }
});
```